# async-validator avoid validation before submitting form

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I use [async-validator](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator) combined with [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#validation).

I would like to execute validation only on submitting form (which actually I do in code).

When using `trigger: 'change'` in the `rules` definition, if I leave a filed with a value which does not comply with the rule, I get an error message:

```
name: [
  { required: true, message: 'Required field', trigger: 'blur' },
  { min: 5, message: 'Name should have at least 5 letters\n', trigger: 'change' }
],
```

[image]

When using `trigger: 'blur'`, I get an error message even before I leave the field:

```
name: [
  { required: true, message: 'Required field', trigger: 'blur' },
  { min: 5, message: 'Name should have at least 5 letters\n', trigger: 'blur' }
],
```

[image]

I tried to use `validate-on-rule-change`, but it doesn't help:

```
<el-form ref="addressForm" :inline="true"
         :model="formData" :rules="addressRules" class="demo-form-inline"
         :validate-on-rule-change="false"
>
```

Comment: Hey did you find solution to this? Would be so grateful if you had. Im trying to figure it out for days but no help at all. Thanks.

Comment: No @gitamgadtaula, still having the same behavior..

Comment: But if you find this question useful @gitam, you can upvote it, hopefully somebody will supply some good answer.

Comment: I have added the answer below. Please upvote it if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do

```
name: {
    required: true, 
    message: "Please enter name ", 
    trigger: 'submit' // Only triggers when $refs.form.validate() is called
},
```

Comment: Thanks!! Have no idea how come I didn't find it. Anyway, now using it I realize it is helpful to use `trigger: 'blur'` in order to see immediately validation status.

Answer (score 0):

maybe change your rule so you have a trigger inside :

```
required_blur: {
    required: true, 
    message: "Donnée obligatoire", 
    trigger: 'blur' // When focus changes in the input it triggers
},
required_change: {
    required: true, 
    message: "Donnée obligatoire", // When input's value changes
    trigger: 'change'
},
```

good luck :)

Comment: I have just edited my question thanks to your response. These two options trigger validation **before** form is submitted, so it does not solve my problem.